# Remove particular GMSMarker from GMSMapview using Google Map sdk in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am integrating google maps sdk. Its all work fine. But how to remove particular Marker(Pin Point) when second will appear.(I am not using Mapkit)

I want the following:

If i tap on map then one marker pin is generate at that location now if i tap on another location on map then two pins are displayed but i want to remove the old marker pin.

I also use,

```
[self.mapView clear];
```

But it was clear all other marker points from GMSMapview.

Following is the code to add pin on Map:

```
            GMSMapView *mapView;
            GMSMarker *currLocMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
            currLocMarker.map  = nil;
            [currLocMarker setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"current_location_title", nil)];
            currLocMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_fetch_location.png"];
            currLocMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pCoordinate.latitude, pCoordinate.longitude);
            currLocMarker.map = self.mapView;
```

Please help me to solve out this stuff..!!

Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: Please add your code snippet how you add Marker on map,than it will possible to understand.

Comment: I also use that but its can't work..

Comment: @jigs did you find out the way? i also want to move my particular marker. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I got that solution.
Add pin like the following:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinates {

pCoordinate.latitude =coordinates.latitude;
pCoordinate.longitude =coordinates.longitude;

[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *resp, NSError *error)
                {
     [currLocMarker setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"current_location_title", nil)];
     currLocMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
     currLocMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinates.latitude,       coordinates.longitude);
     currLocMarker.map = self.mapView;} ] ;}
```

Please remove the following line if you used in the above:

```
GMSMarker *currLocMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
```

Comment: Hello, I'm having a very similar problem to you, however I'm generating markers in a loop and want to remove those markers, not just one. I tried your implementation but it didn't seem to work. Can you possible look at my post? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811920/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-marker-is-present-on-the-google-map-to-delete-it

Answer (score 28):

To remove a particular pin from GMSMapView keep reference of pin (if there are multiple then use array) then use this code

```
currLocMarker.map  = nil;
```

To remove all things including pins poly lines from GMSMapView use this code

```
[ _mapView clear];
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me -

```
func removeMarkers(mapView: GMSMapView){
    for (index, _) in markers.enumerate() {
        //print("Item \(index): \(element)")
                    self.markers[index].map = nil
    }
}
```

where

```
    var markers = [GMSMarker]()
```

markers contains all the marker overlays for the mapView

Comment: Hi, Why you receive a GMSMapView if you wouldn't use it?

Answer (score 2):

I made like this:

```
GMSMarker *myMarker;

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (myMarker) {
            myMarker.map = nil;
            myMarker = nil;
        }
        myMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        myMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
        myMarker.title = @"title";
        myMarker.map = mapView_;
    }];
}
```

and worked well for me !

Answer (score 1):

Check This one and try it in your code

[Remove a marker in Google Maps sdk](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker#remove_a_marker)

Answer (score 1):

loop all marker in the map , and you can use title or snippet to decide which marker you remove

as map.markers is no longer to use in google map ios sdk , you need to have a nsmutablearray to store all marker for looping purpose

and you can make use of userData of the marker , marker.userData , which i prefer to store a nsdictionary information in the marker in order to prevent from duplicate name of title .

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

When you tap on specific marker this will remove that marker

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {

    marker.map = nil;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 5

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool
{
    let alertcontrolserver = UIAlertController.init(title : nil, message : "Are you sure you want to Remove ! ", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okbtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { UIAlertAction in  marker.map = nil
             })
    let cancelbtn = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertcontrolserver.addAction(okbtn)
       alertcontrolserver.addAction(cancelbtn)
        self.present(alertcontrolserver, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you have different markers, and you want to remove only specific markers from the map, then you have to hold that marker(s) object.

```
say if you have 
var removableMarkers: [GMSMarker]?

you have to append those markers in the above array when adding markers to map

Now, when you want to remove those markers:
  _ = self.removableMarkers.map({
            $0.map = nil
        })
self.RemovableMarkers = []
```

That's it!